# How to add a new empty the element

Tags: xslt

There are messages:

```
<Employees xmlns="https://services">
    <Employee>
        <SNILS>111-111-111-2</SNILS>
        <Name>Elena</Name>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

Output should be look like this:

```
<Employees xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://services">
    <Employee>
        <SNILS>111-111-111-2</SNILS>
        <Name>Elena</Name>
        <Sex i:nil="true"/>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

how to get such a result?

Comment: How far have you come by trying yourself? Can you show your XSLT so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use identity transform

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="t:Employee">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        <t:Sex i:nil="true" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

t: is prefix for your namespace `https://services`.